# UI-GRID column summation on checkbox change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

Does anyone know why when I click on different radio values multiple times, my Dynamic Total value changes drastically? 
The code below should automatically select the column of checkboxes according to the radio buttons. Not sure why there would be miscalculations.

```
switch($scope.ChangeAll.name) {
                case 'x':
              row.xBox = true;
                    row.yBox = false;
                    row.zBox = false;
                break;
                case 'y':
              row.xBox = false;
                    row.yBox = true;
                    row.zBox = false;
                break;
                case 'z':
              row.xBox = false;
                    row.yBox = false;
                    row.zBox = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    row.xBox = true;
                    row.yBox = false;
                    row.zBox = false;

                }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/bAnz9kCuKWGIfWD4lEO2?p=preview

Comment: what is the challenge you are facing?

Comment: The "Dynamic Total" is the sum of the product column. The Dynamic Total is incorrect when you select the radio button multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tweak should do it.

[image: angularjs ui-grid]

AngularJS Controller (relevant code change):

```
$scope.updateSelection = function(value) {
  switch ($scope.ChangeAll.name) {
    case 'x':
      angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(row, idx) {
        row.xBox = true;
        row.yBox = false;
        row.zBox = false;
      });
      break;
    case 'y':
      angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(row, idx) {
        row.xBox = false;
        row.yBox = true;
        row.zBox = false;
      });
      break;
    case 'z':
      angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(row, idx) {
        row.xBox = false;
        row.yBox = false;
        row.zBox = true;
      });
      break;
    default:
      angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(row, idx) {
        row.xBox = true;
        row.yBox = false;
        row.zBox = false;
      });
  }
};
```

And the all important Plunker update, https://plnkr.co/edit/QOkoG9pC7gETvZ4I7Xkq?p=preview.

Comment: You're amazing! Thank you Tim!

Comment: No worries, happy to help.  Feel free to keep posting questions as you work through things.  You're too kind :-)!

Comment: Hi Tim, Sorry to bother you, but do you know if this is possible? Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452977/how-to-handle-dynamic-dropdowns-for-ui-grid

Comment: No worries.  I provided an answer, I hope it helps!