# How to handle dynamic dropdowns for ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

- I’m trying to add a dropdown to my “Type” column where I can select either x, y, or z.
- When I select x, y, or z  in the dropdown, the checkboxes for the x, y, z columns don’t  change.
- However, when I check the either x,y or z checkboxes, the downdrop value in the “Type” column changes

  ```
  { name: 'Type', displayName: 'Type', width: '7%',field:'getType()',  editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor', 
           editDropdownValueLabel: 'Type', enableCellEdit: true },
  ```

Here's my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/mzSaxh3PVvqvfJtAYKkU?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

This should do it...

```
$scope.updateType = function (entity, type) {
  entity.xBox = type == 'x';
  entity.yBox = type == 'y';
  entity.zBox = type == 'z';
}

editableCellTemplate: '<select ui-grid-edit-dropdown ng-init="result=row.entity.getType()" ng-options="type for type in [\'x\',\'y\',\'z\']" ng-model="result" ng-change="grid.appScope.updateType(row.entity, result)"></select>'
```

Your Plunker updated, https://plnkr.co/edit/SbZkKubGtrzWYJhc8Qv9?p=preview.

Comment: Interesting. Here's an updated plunker: [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/XgT7XxSjpLAK9UJCjhHE?p=preview)
When I check Own Value, I want the Type column to reflect the last x,y,or z that was checked.

Comment: Ignore the previous comment. Here's the updated comment: plunker: [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/XgT7XxSjpLAK9UJCjhHE?p=preview)
When Own Value is checked, the Type column cell should always reflect the last x,y,or z that was unchecked. Type only reflects xyz when I check either x,y, or z boxes. If Own value is checked, the product would be Own Value * qty. Type is not reflecting xy|z when Own Value is checked. Is this possible? Thank you so much for your patience.

Comment: Was my answer above helpful at least, if it didn't actually answer your original question?